# Could you suggest basic mathematics textbooks (calculus, linear algebra) that are written in an intuitive manner?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, education

For instance, I really loved reading the book " Div, Grad, Curl, and All That" by H.M.Schey. I would like texts closely written in that particular style.

Comment: There is a linear algebra there is a book called "Linear Algebra done Right" that I think is universally considered a pretty bomb book.

Comment: Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths has a great intuitive explanation of vector calculus. I learned a lot from it. I think Gilbert Strang's books on linear algebra and his book Introduction to Applied Math have great intuition. The book Visual Complex Analysis is highly intuitive. Quantum Computing Since Democritus is a very insightful book on computational complexity. Spivak's Hitchiker's Guide to Calculus focuses on intuition.

Answer (score 4):

One option for an intuitive - yet comprehensive and rigorous - textbook is Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*. It is great for students who would like a well-motivated introduction to real analysis that provides good intuition for what is going on. Michael Spivak's *Calculus* textbook is another analysis-heavy calculus textbook that I think is very intuitive.

If you have an abstract algebra background, I've enjoyed reading through *Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist* - it's a very relaxed tour through the basics of geometric group theory and some neat associated problems, along with a brief group theory refresher.

I'll also second littleO's suggestion of *Visual Complex Analysis* - if you prefer visual arguments this is a well-known and helpful introduction to basic complex analysis.